# How to properly format nested inner joins in Access SQL?

Tags: sql, count, sql-order-by, inner-join

I have the following tables:

```
   VENDOR:          PRODUCT:           ITEM:             STORE:
-  VENDOR_ID     -  PRODUCT_ID      -  ITEM_ID        -  STORE_ID
-  VENDOR_NAME   -  PRODUCT_DESC    -  STORE_ID       -  STORE_NAME
                 -  VENDOR_ID       -  PRODUCT_ID     -  STORE_LOCATION
                                    -  ITEM_PRICE
```

I want to perform the following join operations, but I'm not sure how to format it with Access SQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT VENDOR.VENDOR_NAME, COUNT(ITEM.PRODUCT_CODE)
FROM VENDOR INNER JOIN PRODUCT ON VENDOR.VENDOR_ID = PRODUCT.VENDOR_ID
INNER JOIN ITEM ON PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID = ITEM.PRODUCT_ID
GROUP BY VENDOR.VENDOR_NAME
ORDER BY COUNT(ITEM.PRODUCT_ID) DESC;
```

Could you please tell me the correct way to nest INNER JOINs like this? I'm using Access!

Comment: I already answered your question in the previous question you posted Lane. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM (VENDOR
INNER JOIN PRODUCT ON VENDOR.VENDOR_ID = PRODUCT.VENDOR_ID) 
INNER JOIN ITEM ON PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID = ITEM.PRODUCT_ID
```

The only thing you were missing was the parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods that a database engine can use to join two tables. The method used is being chosen by what the database knows about the size and the data in the tables and can have a huge impact on the overall performance.

And think about inner joins: Isn't the result always the same, no matter the order?

The query optimizer might improve the query by rearranging the joins and therefore you should never specify any nesting in SQL. Just leave it to the pros (in this case: an algorithm).